# How do I get the information of a batch script started in java, whether it has already ended

Tags: java, processbuilder

im calling multiple batch files in Java with the ProcessBuilder like

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "Start", "batchTest.bat"); 
File dir = new File(path);
processBuilder.directory(dir);
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now i want the information that the script is done in java. Like just a sysout when the script is completly finished. `process.isAlive()` turns false before the script is done. And also `process.witFor()` doesnt get the job done. Maybe someone has an idea or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it. `process.waitFor()` only works if you add the parameter `"/wait"` to the Constructor of the ProcessBuilder.

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "Start", "/wait", "batchTest.bat");
```